# How to connect to Registry On another Computer and Read Data in c#

Tags: c#

Please Help Me To How connect to Registry On another Computer and Read Data in c#.

I am Search in Google and see All Sample Code But None Samples not Connect to Remote machine Registry In Network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it out, 
Create a RegistryKey and use the following method on it

```
aKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(
    RegistryHive.CurrentUser,
    remoteHost).OpenSubKey("ASubKeyName");
```

Do not forget that you need enough security permission to do this, for example if you are about to do this in a domained network and you are granted sufficient privileges by being a member of Administrators, the above code will work. You may check `system.security.permission` before executing above code or catch security exception.

Answer (score 0):

Iman already provided a good answer, and I would suggest using his if you have the infrastructure (i.e. a domain) and you can get the permissions working. Otherwise, you can create your own simple TCP server that provides access to the registry, then write a client to connect to it. However, if you choose this approach, **please remember to use encryption and authentication!!!** Otherwise, you will leave yourself open to a security nightmare.